# Problems with bluetooth headphones after pairing

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have been struggling a lot to connect my Philips SHB7150 bluetooth headphones to 16.04, but keep getting recurrent problems even after connection. I checked and tried various solutions I found here and elsewhere, but none of them completely works.

1. **Connection**
   Usually this step goes well, but not always. I installed Bluetooth Manager (blueman), but it does not seem to make much difference (since there is already a Bluetooth app under Settings). I'm still trying to figure out why it sometimes does not connect, but after restarting various things it usually works again.
2. **Playback**
   Most of the time, even if it connects it does not switch to AD2P. If I try to set it to AD2P through either Bluetooth Manager or the default Bluetooth program, then it gets rejected (and switches to my built-in speakers). Sometimes it does connect properly and seems to switch to AD2P, but there is still no audio and files do not play (e.g. YouTube, but also pure audio files).

**Things I have tried**

- Connecting and reconnecting and restarting programs sometimes solves the problem. However, its working is very inconsistent. Strangely, it has worked well several times.
- I noticed that the file under `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` was empty at the beginning. I have now edited it to include

  ```
  [General]
  Disable=Headset
  Enable=Socket
  AutoConnect=true
  ```
- I also installed PulseAudio Volume Control (`pavucontrol`), but it does not always succeed in setting audio to AD2P. Sometimes when I do that, the audio of my apps under 'Playback' switches back to built-in speakers and I cannot set it to my headphones. Other times it does take the setting, but then there is still no sound.
- I tried logging my bluetooth connection. After connecting to the headphones, in its currently non-functional state it shows the following message (which I do not understand):

  ```
  Feb 12 17:10:11 username-UX32LA pulseaudio[1645]: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-device.c: Default profile not connected, selecting off profile
  Feb 12 17:10:11 username-UX32LA bluetoothd[977]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1E_7C_4F_55_B9/fd6: fd(35) ready
  Feb 12 17:10:11 username-UX32LA rtkit-daemon[1250]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
  Feb 12 17:10:11 username-UX32LA rtkit-daemon[1250]: Successfully made thread 10271 of process 1645 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
  Feb 12 17:10:11 username-UX32LA rtkit-daemon[1250]: Supervising 5 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
  Feb 12 17:10:11 username-UX32LA pulseaudio[1645]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Transport TryAcquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1E_7C_4F_55_B9/fd6 (Operation Not Authorized)
  Feb 12 17:10:11 username-UX32LA kernel: [13004.473401] input: 00:1E:7C:4F:55:B9 as /devices/virtual/input/input34
  ```